# Uso de val() no script me faz perder quebras de linha

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, java-ee, jsp

Estou com um problema. Estou implementando uma página de chat, utilizando o seguinte script:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#enviar").click(function(){
                    var mensagem = $("#campodetexto").val();
                    var old = $("#conteudojanela").html();
                    var hora = (new Date).getHours();
                    var min = (new Date).getMinutes();
                    if(min <10)
                        min = "0"+min;
                    var sec = (new Date).getSeconds();
                    if(sec <10)
                        sec = "0"+sec;
                    var horario = hora+":"+min+":"+sec;
                    var nmsg = old + "<div class=\"user\"><div class=\"colunm01\"><p class=\"atendenteBold\">Cliente</p><p>"+horario+"</p></div><div class=\"colunm02\"><p>"+mensagem+"</p></div></div>";
                    $("#conteudo").html(nmsg);
                });
        });
        </script>
```

O que ocorre é que perco todas as quebras de linha que faço ao digitar o texto.
Trocar a chamada do `var mensagem = $("#campodetexto").val();`para `.text();` ou `.html();` me faz perder o valor, e chamar `replace()` não tem funcionado com trocas entre `\n`, `\\n` e/ou `<br>`.

Sei que estou fazendo algo errado, preciso saber apenas o que é. Já busquei dezenas de tutoriais na internet e nada me ajudou.

Obrigado desde já.

------ EDIT:
O que quero, é que ao digitar um texto na chatbox(`"#campodetexto"`), o texto vá para a tela de chat(`"#conteudo"`) com todas as quebras de linha(`[ENTER]`) que eu tiver digitado, e isto não tem acontecido. A quebra de linha é mostrada no chatbox, mas não na janela de chat.

Comment: Utiliza o append, ficando `$("#conteudo").append($('<div>...</div>'))`,

Comment: sim. Se resolver faço resposta a explicar o que se estava a passar e a resolução

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer fazer ainda.

Comment: KhaosDoctor, quero que ao clicar no botão, o texto digitado vá para a tela de chat com as quebras de linha que eu digitar no campo de texto.

Comment: Cesar, desculpe apagar meu comment. Foi sem querer.

Comment: Vê este Fiddle que fiz agora e diz-me se é isso que queres: http://jsfiddle.net/2gys5ou1/1/

Comment: @CesarMiguel, ele exibe o texto, porém não exibe a quebra de linha.
Eu digito um texto:
"Olá. \n
Preciso de ajuda."
E aparece na janela: "Olá. Preciso de ajuda."

Comment: Exacto, já entendi. Vou ver o que posso fazer

Comment: Se você está inserindo *div*'s, você precisa garantir que o CSS as organize de forma a não ficarem na mesma linha. Setar a propriedade `display` do CSS para `inline-block` pode ajudar.

Comment: @igorfeiden, já atualizei e a funcionar. Agora é só uma questão de ajustar o texto, mas basicamente é isto, certo? http://jsfiddle.net/2gys5ou1/3/

Comment: @Renan, não funcionou sua sugestão, mas obrigado!

Comment: @CesarMiguel, Funcionou perfeitamente; muito obrigado!
Podes responder, marcarei como resolvida.
Novamente, agradeço.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O que podes fazer é um `.replace` de um `\n` por `<br />` para poder ser interpretado de forma correta:

```
var mensagem = $("#campodetexto").val();
var text = mensagem.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
```

Depois, em vez de usares o `.html` como estás a usar, basta usares o `.append` para acrescentar texto no teu chat:

```
$("#conteudo").append($('<br/><label>'+horario+': '+text+'</label>'))
```

Código completo:

```
$("#enviar").click(function(){
    var mensagem = $("#campodetexto").val();

    var hora = (new Date).getHours();
    var min = (new Date).getMinutes();
    if(min <10)
        min = "0"+min;
    var sec = (new Date).getSeconds();
    if(sec <10)
        sec = "0"+sec;
    var horario = hora+":"+min+":"+sec;

    var text = mensagem.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');

    $("#conteudo").append($('<br/><label>'+horario+': '+text+'</label>'))
});
```

LINK [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gys5ou1/4/)

Comment: Exato.
Obrigado!

Comment: Estamos cá para ajudar ;)