# Preservar quebra de linha ao Replicar conteúdo de val() em span

Tags: jquery, textarea, quebras-de-linha

Boa tarde, de acordo com este [tópico - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203969/replicar-conte%C3%BAdo-de-val-em-span](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203969/replicar-conte%C3%BAdo-de-val-em-span) possuo o seguinte código

```
$('textarea.skills_knowledge').blur(function() {
    var skills_knowledge = $(this).val();
    $('span.skills_knowledge').html(skills_knowledge); });
```

gostaria de saber como preservar as quebras de linha, ou seja, se apertar o enter no text área, aparecer isso no span devidamente um abaixo do outro

não sei se é o melhor formato, aceito sugestões de melhoria, mas achei este formato no [tópico -https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40803/uso-de-val-no-script-me-faz-perder-quebras-de-linha?rq=1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40803/uso-de-val-no-script-me-faz-perder-quebras-de-linha?rq=1)

```
$('textarea.skills_knowledge').blur(function() {
    var skills_knowledge = $(this).val();
    var skills_knowledge = skills_knowledge.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
    $('span.skills_knowledge').html(skills_knowledge); });
```

Comment: não sei exatamente se isso pode ajudar, http://jsfiddle.net/Wm9um vou fazer uns testes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse código vai substituir todas as quebras de linha `\n` em tags `<br/>`, as combinações são para funcionar em diversos navegadores.

```js
$('textarea.skills_knowledge').blur(function() {
  var skills_knowledge = $(this).val();
  skills_knowledge = skills_knowledge.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, "<br/>");
  $('span.skills_knowledge').html(skills_knowledge);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="skills_knowledge"></textarea>

<span class="skills_knowledge"></span>
```

Comment: i, legal, mesma solução que achei, mas o seu está mais completo, obrigado